# Checkbox "Use Website" doesn't work after adding new website

Tags: magento2, configuration, view, checkbox

I am learning ["Set up multiple views in the Admin"](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/multi-sites/ms-admin.html?lang=en)

1. I added a new website+store+view
2. then opened store > system > configuration > general > web and tried to change store url. But checkbox doesn't active.

I select any store or view, result is the same. Now I can't change any setting of any view.

HTML inspector shows:

- checkbox readonly="1"
- disabled="disabled"